# how to add &reg; symbol in meta tag in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, meta-tags

I am trying to add ® symbol in meta tag of my aspx page.

Below is my meta tag

```
<meta property="og:title" content="eShop &reg; XXXYXYXX | eShop® Brand"/>
```

but the symbol is not reflected in the title. 
I found few suggesstions in google that the meta values can be added by code behind. But I cannot use the code-behind way in my page.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks

**EDIT**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="eShop &reg; XXXYXYXX | eShop® Brand"/>
```

Comment: Have you specified the charset of the page before using the special character? i.e `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: yes. I have specified the meta charset in my page as first tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

`<meta property="og:title" content="eShop &#174; XXXYXYXX | eShop® Brand"/>`

Comment: in page source, the tag value is displayed as same eShop &#174; and not the symbol

Comment: i am not sure , if it will show in `page source`, but it should show in actual rendered page title.